# Panel metrics give better t-statistics than Information Coefficients?

Tags: factor-analysis

In finance, factor analysis is used to model the forecast returns of stocks:

$$r_i = \alpha_i + \beta_1f_{i1} + \cdots + \beta_Kf_{iK} + \epsilon_i$$
where

- $r_i$ is the next return of stock $i$
- $\alpha_i$ is the part of the return unexplained by factors,
- $f_{i1},..., f_{iK}$ are *factor exposures* (could be something like market cap, price-to-earnings ratio, or some other stock-specific thing),
- $\beta_1,..., \beta_k$ are the *factor premiums* we obtain through a regression analysis, and
- $\epsilon_i$ is an error term.

Normally, to determine the validity of a single factor $f$, one would compute its $t$-statistic.  An accepted way of doing this is to compute the cross-sectional *Spearman Rank IC* at each point in time by computing the correlation of the ranks of the factor exposure.  i.e. if $f_{i,t}$ is the factor exposure of $f$ for stock $i$ at time $t$, and $r_{i,t}$ is the return of stock $i$ at time $t$, we want to compute the correlation of the factor ranks $R(f_{i,t-1})$ against the ranks of next month's return $R(r_{i,t})$ at each point in time.  Then, compute the $t$-statistic of this time series of *IC*'s in the usual way:  $t$-stat $= \mu\sqrt{n}/\sigma$, where $n$ is the length of the series and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and standard deviation.

At the moment, an idea doing the rounds among quantitative analysts is to compute the so-called *rank of Covariance Units*:
$$RankCU_{i,f,t} = (R(f_{i,t-1}) - \frac{N_t}{2}) \cdot (R(r_{i,t}) - \frac{N_t}{2})$$
(Here, $N_t$ is the number of stocks in the universe at each time $t$.)  The $t$-statistics derived from these $\{RankCU_{i,f,t}\}_{i,t}$ numbers tend to be higher than the $t$-statistics derived from the usual *IC* time series.

My question is:  is there any reason to accept this alternative methodology?  Does this panel metric have any academically accepted history, or is it just something the local quant brokers have made up because it gives better-looking numbers?

Comment: Note that the number of stocks might change through time.  For example, if one chooses the MSCI AC World as a test universe, there would be over 2000 stocks today versus approximately 500 stocks twenty years ago.  Could there be some kind of bias towards periods where there are more stocks?